# Необязательное условие в WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица task

```
ID TaskName
```

Колонка ID связана с другой таблицей - users

```
ID TaskID UserName UserID
```

запись в таблице users может быть а может не быть.

Я хочу вывести task по его ID + UserID (если он есть).

Пробую сделать так `SELECT task.ID, users.UserName FROM task JOIN users WHERE users.UserID = 1 AND task.ID=4`

Если пользователь есть - оно выводит нужную запись. Если нет, ответ не содержит записи.
Пытаюсь сделать, что бы ответ был в любом случае (есть пользователь или нет). Если пользователя нет то вывести в колонке `users.UserName` NULL или 0.
Пробовал делать OR

```
WHERE (users.UserID = 1 AND task.ID=4) OR task.ID=4
```

Но это не сработало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем примере используется `JOIN` или говоря [INNER JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_join_inner.asp). При данном соединении таблиц исключаются все записи, несвязанные по ключу `task.ID` - `users.TaskID`. И в результате, в поле `users.UserName` не будут выводится значения с `NULL`.

Для решения данной задачки попробуйте использовать [LEFT JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_join_left.asp):

```
SELECT
  t.Id,
  u.UserName
FROM
  task t
  LEFT JOIN users u ON u.TaskId = t.Id
WHERE
  t.Id = 4
```